# Evitar comilla (') al usar INSERT en java

Tags: java, mariadb

Buenas,

Me estoy encontrando con un problema a la hora de realizar el comando `INSERT` en java. Uno de los campos es el nombre del juego, y al estar en inglés hay algunos que incluyen una comilla ('), es por ello que si por ejemplo el nombre del juego que tiene que introducir es Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six, java sólo me está cogiendo Tom Clancy, y el programa deja de ejecutarse por el siguiente error: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's Rainbow Six Siege'' at line 1`. Esa línea corresponde con la línea en la que uso `INSERT`.

El código que estoy usando:

```
public class Conectate {
private String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private String cadenaConexion ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/XboxOne";
private String pass = "";
private String usuario = "root";
public Connection con;

//public Conectate(Map<String,  Map<String, Item>> gamesByCountry, Map<String, String> codesByTitle,Map<String, String> countries) {
public Conectate(ArrayList<Item> games) {    

    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(cadenaConexion, usuario, pass);
        System.out.println("¡Conectado!");


        //CREAMOS LA TABLA
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info_XboxOne (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), "
                + "Juego_vinculado VARCHAR(500), Juego VARCHAR(500), Tipologia VARCHAR (500), Pertenece VARCHAR (500), "
                + "Nota VARCHAR (10), Descripcion_Ingles TEXT(4000), Descripcion_Castellano TEXT(4000), Pegi VARCHAR(10), Descripcion_Pegi VARCHAR(200),"
                + "Lanzamiento VARCHAR (50))");

        System.out.println( "Tabla creada!");


        for (Item game : games) {

            String titulo = game.getName();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = '" + titulo + "'");

            if (!rs.next()) { //si se cumple esta condicción significa que el juego no está incluido, con lo que lo metemos
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO info_XboxOne (Juego, Tipologia, Pertenece, "
                + "Nota, Descripcion_Ingles, Descripcion_Castellano, Pegi, Descripcion_Pegi"
                + ") VALUES (?,?,?,?"
                + ",?,?,?,?"
                + ")");

                ps.setString(1,game.getName());
                ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
                ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
                ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
                ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
                ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
                ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
                ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));    

                ps.executeUpdate();

            } else {
                String query = "UPDATE info_XboxOne SET Tipologia = ?, Pertenece = ?, "
                + "Nota = ?, Descripcion_Ingles = ?, Descripcion_Castellano = ?, "
                + "Pegi = ?, Descripcion_Pegi = ? WHERE juego = " + titulo;
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

                ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
                ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
                ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
                ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
                ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
                ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
                ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));

                ps.executeUpdate();
            }           
        }

} catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido establecer la conexión con la DB" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public String ConvertirObjectToString(Object Obj) {
String Str="";
if(Obj!=null){
    Str = Obj.toString();
}
return Str;
}  
}
```

¿Hay alguna forma para evitar que las comillas del nombre no supongan un problema para la ejecución? Me pasaría también con otro campo, pero éste que comento es el que primero me ha saltado.

Comment: ya probaste asi: "' + titulo + '", comilla doble, comilla simple,comilla simple, comilla doble?

Comment: Es extraño que esté dando ese error. Veo que estás usando preparedstatemets. Cuando los usas no necesitas hacer scape de las comillas, pues el preparedstatement lo hace por ti. Yo trataría de crear una cadena completa del INSERT INTO..., imprimirla en consola y revisarla... quizá haya algo que esté entrando en la cadena de inserción por otra lado, lo digo porque veo que haces por ejemplo: `ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));` ¿agregas algo más a lo que insertas en cada columna? 
 Por cierto, ¿por qué en los statement de UPDATE comienzas los set... por el número 2?

Comment: Siendo que al final te distes cuenta que el error estaba en el `SELECT` y no el `INSERT`, queda claro que, a diferencia de lo que afirmastes en la pregunta, el error no provenía del `INSERT`. Para evitar este tipo de confusiones, siempre es útil que incluyas el error + el stack trace (pila de llamadas). La causa del error hubiera sido más obvio entonces.

Answer (score 2):

Para evitar estos problemas de comillas simples, es importante usar parámetros con `PreparedStatement`s, en vez de concatenar valores en la cadena SQL directamente. Veo que ya lo haces correctamente con tu sentencia `INSERT`. Te falta hacerlo también con tu `SELECT`. No solo te evitará esta clase de problemas, pero también te protegerá de ataques de inyección SQL.

Aprovecho para recomendarte también que uses el patrón [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) a la hora de manejar objetos de tipo `PreparedStatement` y/o `ResultSet` para evitar mantener abiertos los recursos más tiempo de lo necesario.

De modo que, en vez de:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = '" + titulo + "'");

// usar rs...
```

La forma correcta de hacerlo sería:

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = ?")) {
    ps.setString(1, titulo);

    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        // usar rs...
    }
}
```

**Edición**

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo más completo que aplica a tu caso. Aprovecho también para corregir tu `UPDATE` que sufre del mismo problema que tu `SELECT`, y además no numeraba tus parámetros correctamente:

```
for (Item game : games) {
    String titulo = game.getName();

    boolean isInsert;
    try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = ?")) {
        ps.setString(1, titulo);

        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            isInsert = !rs.next();
        }
    }

    if (isInsert) { //si se cumple esta condicción significa que el juego no está incluido, con lo que lo metemos
        try(PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO info_XboxOne (Juego, Tipologia, Pertenece, "
            + "Nota, Descripcion_Ingles, Descripcion_Castellano, Pegi, Descripcion_Pegi"
            + ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")) {

            ps.setString(1,titulo);
            ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
            ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
            ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
            ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
            ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
            ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
            ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));    

            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    } else {
        String query = "UPDATE info_XboxOne SET Tipologia = ?, Pertenece = ?, "
        + "Nota = ?, Descripcion_Ingles = ?, Descripcion_Castellano = ?, "
        + "Pegi = ?, Descripcion_Pegi = ? WHERE juego = ?";

        try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
            ps.setString(1,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
            ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
            ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
            ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
            ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
            ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
            ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));
            ps.setString(8,titulo);

            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: Buenas, ¿qué es lo que tendría que ir lo que indicas con `//usar rs...`? No conocía esa estructura. Entiendo que dentro debería ir todo el condicional `if (!rs.next()) {...`.

Comment: Hice una edición a la respuesta para que puedas ver un ejemplo completo.

Comment: Tengo un problema, me indica `try-with-resources is not supported in - source 1.5`

Comment: Por el error, parece que aunque estás usando una versión de Java mas reciente, la configuración de la compilación te está limitando a usar la sintaxis de Java 1.5. No sé que herramienta usas para tu desarollo, pero busca la manera de cambiar el "source level" de la compilación para que use la versión correspondiente al Java que usas. Necesitas por lo menos estar al nivel de Java 7 para poder usar el `try-with-resources`. Y si puedes subirlo a la versión 8, aun mejor.

Comment: Lo he podido subir al nivel 9, era el más alto, no me daba opción de 7 u 8. Estoy ejecutando el programa ahora. La duda que tengo es, ¿realmente es necesario si sólo lo voy a ejecutar yo en local? Ahora mismo el código que tengo me funciona bien, salvo por una cosa.

Comment: Eso tu lo decides. Pero en lo personal, si tomo la pena de contestar una pregunta, trato de incluir las mejores prácticas para el beneficio de los futuros lectores. Y el uso de `try-with-resources` con este tipo de objetos es una muy buena práctica.

Comment: Razón no te falta, incluir lo voy a incluir, estoy a la espera de ver los resultados, gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado usando `\"` en vez de las comillas simples:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE juego = \"" + titulo + "\"");
```

Comment: Me alegro que tu problema está solucionado, pero para beneficio de los demás lectores, esta solución en realidad no es recomendable. La forma correcta es, como ya se te comentó, de usar un parámetro en un `PreparedStatement`. Es más, el uso de comillas dobles no es SQL estándar, y no funcionará en cualquier motor de bases de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Usa Hibernate o JPA en su defecto. Es mucho más eficiente y las posibilidades de que un Hacker te haga SQLInjection son mucho más bajas en comparación al código que estás implementando.

Algunos links de referencia:

[How-To de Hibernate](http://www.cursohibernate.es/doku.php?id=unidades:02_hibernate:04_usando_hibernate)
[How-To de JPA](http://www.uv.es/grimo/teaching/SpringMVCv3PasoAPaso/part5.html)

Finalmente, no es una buena práctica modificar el modelo de datos desde tu código fuente, hablando desde un aspecto de diseño y mantención de software.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día.

Para este tipo de casos te recomendaría utilizar los **PreparedStatement**, ademas de que te evita realizar el uso de comillas (ya que los valores se pasan por parámetros), con las sentencias **Select** son mucho mas seguros y evitan la **inyección de código SQL** en tu consulta, como lo comentan arriba.

En cuanto **hibernate o JPA**, si tu necesitas portabilidad entre bases de datos (cambiar fácilmente de una base de datos a otra), si es recomendable, ademas que los **ORM** tienen puntos en contra, entre ellos: la velocidad y carga de objetos que genera, ya que en un ORM todas las tablas que genera son objetos.

Con esto no quiero decir que Hibernate o JPA no sirvan, solo que su uso depende de tus necesidades.

Yo los utilizaría en sistemas que requieren portabilidad de base de datos o que la carga de trabajo no sea tan demandante (sistemas de gestión por ejemplo). Estos frameworks de BD se pueden optimizar en cuanto a velocidad, por ejemplo hibernate utiliza una cache para saber con que objetos tratas, guardas o actualizas y los almacena ahí para tenerlos disponibles la proxima vez que lo necesites, pero ojo, solo se quedan por un tiempo y después el framework los desecha.

Te dejo un link para que veas un ejemplo de los PrepareStatement.
[Ejemplo PrepareStatement](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/)